# How to sync ram disk of one server to another

Tags: linux, rsync, nfs, ramdisk

I have created ram disk as  /mnt/ramdisk/test in both server A and B. Where I will be writing dedicated content in each server's ram disk.

Now, i want the content of ram disk in server A to sync with server B...

I have tried nfs mount and soft link... But not working... It stops the process of writing server B since both folder is same name ...

Please suggest any other possible way to sync these two folders in real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) to sync these 2 folders via SSH, make sure you have created them already.